# What does "with trolls" modify in "I have a special gift with trolls"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, modifiers, qualifiers

> "Certainly. I have a special gift **with trolls**, -- you must have seen what I did to the one in the chamber back there?"

From Harry Potter and the Philosopher's/Sorcerer's Stone

I really don't know which "with trolls" modifies/qualifies here. Could you teach me?

Comment: *Syntactically*, it's possible for ***with trolls*** to attach to the verb ***have*** rather than the noun ***gift***. Which would mean that myself and the trolls are joint owners of some (unspecified) "gift". Context is everything, but we can *probably* disregard that possible parsing on pragmatic / semantic grounds, even though syntactically it's perfectly valid.

Comment: It's not a modifier but a complement of "gift".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Have a gift" mean "I have a natural skill".  You might say "He has a gift *for* mathematics." or "He is gifted *at* mathematics".

Quirrell is specially skilled at contolling trolls (see book 1).  So he "has a gift".  To describe this gift you use a prepositional phrase.  And a PP headed by "for", "at" or "with" are common. Here, because he has a gift for "fighting with trolls", the author has used "with trolls".

It doesn't matter much if you consider the prepositional phrase as a component of the noun phrase that forms the object "I (have ((a gift) (with trolls)))" or as a component of the clause  "I ((have (a gift)) (with trolls)). The meaning would be the same.

Comment: Without the source which provides essential context,  the phrase "I have a gift **with** trolls" by itself would be (borderline) ungrammatical.

Comment: I think it was Quirrell, having been revealed as the one trying to steal the philosophers stone, boasting, "I do say I have a gift with trolls."

Comment: Even with no other context, I see nothing remotely "(borderline) ungrammatical" about, say, [***She has a gift with animals.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22she+has+a+gift+with+animals%22) And in context, ***trolls*** are just another alternative alongside ***plants, horses, words,...***

Comment: @FumbleFingers fair enough, I couldn't guess what type of gift a wizard etc. could have in "I have a gift with trolls" but "I have a gift with animals" or "for words" etc. are more commonly said and their meaning is more easily understood.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Exactly. We all have a mental list of "subject matters one can have a gift for/with" - it's just that most of us aren't used to talking about being gifted in "troll whispering", or whatever Harry Potter's lot would call it!